# MySQL Database Migration from MySQL 5.7 to 8.0

Tags: mysql

I intend to migrate a database from MySQL Server 5.7 to MySQL Server 8.0. The database is multiple terabytes in size and I simply cannot us mysqldump utility. I researched that the most viable tools for my use case are mysqlbackup or percona xtrabackup. I tried migration with mysqlbackup but failed - the tool can only restore a database backup to a similar version of the server. This is quite limiting. What approach could I possibly use?

Comment: Depending on why is it that you "cannot us mysqldump utility", you could use some sort of logical replication

Comment: It is a multi-terabyte database and a restore from dump is taking weeks. At the same time I am not sure if logical replication would work from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0.36

Comment: @MASHETIALEX *I am not sure if logical replication would work from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0.36*, Yes it works. I always use logical upgrade, only once I faced a unknown thing that I can't remember, easily fixed by removing the line from the backup with sed utility.

Comment: Kindly share a guide on how to upgrade using logical replication from 5.7 to 8.0

Comment: @mustaccio - Can't use replication without first setting up a Replica -- which needs the use of some dump utility!  A "chicken or egg" problem.

Comment: @RickJames You can't create a replica of a database without creating its replica; the purpose of replication is to make the process asynchronous, allowing it to run for as long as it takes, before making the switch, while leaving the origin online.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the entire disk so that you have a backup.

Then install MySQL 8 on top of 5.7.